# Why is my connect with facebook on my site not working?

Tags: authentication, facebook-social-plugins

When I click on the login button on http://www.coupean.com/user/login
I get an error.

What am i doing wrong to setup in Facebook App?

Do I need to touch anything on Open Graph? 
When I want to submit the "like' action it always gives me this message:
No Aggregations created for this Action Type. Please create a completed Aggregation populated with sample data before submitting for review.

so i set up the aggregation...
but I do not know what this actually means and if i am doing them right.
![enter image description here][4]
How can we make the login work? Could you please provide a detailed explanation?

I cannot post up images here so:
please go to
http://www.coupean.com/images/s1.png
http://www.coupean.com/images/s2.png

and s3.png and s4.png under the same root url

Answer (score 0):

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/permissions.request?api_key=APP_ID&app_id=APP_ID&...

You obviously need to insert **your** app's app ID and API key...

Additionally you now need to reset your *app secret* since you just made it public in one of your screenshots.